# Polymer custom component that controls iron-pages

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, custom-component, web-component

I am trying to create a custom Polymer component, which has buttons to control an `iron-page` (pagination and page indicator).

For now, I have created the following component:

```
<dom-module id="my-carousel">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      iron-pages,
      .pagination {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 1em;
        margin: 1em;
      }
    </style>
    <iron-pages selected="0">
      <div>Page 0</div>
      <div>Page 1</div>
      <div>Page 2</div>
      <div>Page 3</div>
    </iron-pages>
    <div class="pagination">
      <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('iron-pages').selectPrevious(); return false;">Previous</a>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ironPages.items}}">
        &nbsp; <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('iron-pages').select({{index}}); return false;">{{index}}</a> &nbsp;
      </template>
      <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('iron-pages').selectNext(); return false;">Next</a>
      <br />
      Page {{ironPages.selected}} of {{ironPages.items.length}}
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-carousel",
      ready: function() {
        this.ironPages = this.$$('iron-pages');
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Live demonstration: http://jsbin.com/rasuqaduhe/edit?html,output

The only things that seem to work are:

- Previous/Next links
- Indicator for total number of pages

**My questions are the following**:

1. The `onclick` attributes look ugly. Is there a proper way to do this?
2. Is there a better way to get the instance of the `iron-page`, or is `this.$$('iron-pages')` OK?
3. Why doesn't the number of the current selected page work?
4. Why doesn't clicking on the page number work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: http://jsbin.com/sesope/edit?html,output

1. The onclick attributes look ugly. Is there a proper way to do this?

   > Annotated event listeners. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners
2. Is there a better way to get the instance of the iron-page, or is this.$$('iron-pages') OK?

   > It's ok but you can also add an `id` to your `iron-pages` element. Polymer automatically builds a map of statically created instance nodes in its local DOM, to provide convenient access to frequently used nodes without the need to query for them manually. Any node specified in the element’s template with an `id` is stored on the `this.$` hash by `id`. https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding
3. Why doesn't the number of the current selected page work?

   > The `iron-pages` element wasn't notified that its `selected` property has changed. But instead of relying on that, you should have declared a `selected` property on your element. Hence this line `<iron-pages selected="{{selected}}" id="pages">` will notify the `iron-pages` element to change the page whenever the `my-carousel`'s `selected` property changes.
4. Why doesn't clicking on the page number work?

   > Adding a `$` sign after `onclick` would actually make it work (`onclick$="Your code"`). But please, don't do that. Use annotated event listeners instead.

Please refer to my jsbin answer so you may have an idea how things work in Polymer land.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect. Just one small concern regarding the `id="pages"` on `iron-pages`. The component will stil work, but there will be two DOM elements with the same `id`. Any way around this? Do I just use a CSS selector like in my original question; or is there a better way?

Comment: You can use another name for the `id`. I only used it as an example.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. The problem is when two `my-carousel` components are placed on the same page. Then both their `iron-pages` will have the same `id` regardless what value I choose.

Comment: @alesc Shadow DOM (and to some extent Shady DOM) encapsulates those stuff. That means that your IDs and styles won't bleed outside of their respective elements as they are only within that element's scope. You can think of the Shadow DOM as a super lean iframe.

Comment: @alesc Please note that Shady DOM is an approximation of Shadow DOM. This means that outside styles would creep inside the element. Shadow DOM, on the other hand, would prevent that.

Comment: @alesc Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/zenuve/edit?html,js,output) showing the encapsulability of Shadow DOM.

Comment: I am trying to integrate your solution but it doesn't work. It is actually very weird, since your JSbin (with editor) works, but the same JSBin (without editor) doesn't work: http://output.jsbin.com/sesope